# problema en la fecha 1970

Tags: php, sql, fpdf

Tengo una variable en mi BD la cual almacena el siguiente valor `FECHA_MOV= "2015-03-19 04:34:20"`

Deseo al momento de imprimir (mostrar) que salga la fecha en este formato `"d-m-Y" ==> 19-03-2015`. Pero me sale la siguiente fecha "01-01-1970"

```
==========codigo============
$pdf->Cell(0,6,$g_chrHead,0,1);
    $originalDate = $rows["FECHA_MOV"];
    $date = new DateTime($originalDate);
    //echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); //esto si funciona
    //echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($originalDate)); // aca sale 01-01-1970

            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',8);

            while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                //echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($rows["FECHA_MOV"]));
                $cad = str_repeat(" ",5) . substr(date("d-m-Y",strtotime($rows["FECHA_MOV"]))       . str_repeat(" ",12),0,14) ;                
                $cad .= substr($rows["NOM_MOV"]     . str_repeat(" ",25),0,27) ;
                $cad .= substr($rows["NOM_PAGO"]    . str_repeat(" ",25),0,27) ;
                $cad .= str_pad(number_format($rows["IMPORTE"],2,".",","), 12, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) ;
                $cad .= str_repeat(" ",3) .substr($rows["NOMBRE"]   . str_repeat(" ",10),0,25) ;
                $pdf->Cell(0,6,$cad,0,1);
            }
        }

======================fin =============
```

como puedo hacer para corregir este error

Comment: `01/01/1970` es el principio del `epoch` de C/Java (la fecha se trata como un número de segundos o milisegundos a partir del `01/01/1970`). Que te salga ese valor apunta a que estas trabajando con un `0`, no con una fecha. Repasa las operaciones que haces desde la BD hasta el texto (incluyendo mostrar los valores intermedios) para asegurarte de que no estes haciendo algo incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente he colocado dentro del while lo siguiente:

```
while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
echo strlen($rows["NOMBRE"]). "<br>"; 
echo $rows["NOMBRE"];
```

Me arroja datos, pero cuando hago esto:

```
while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
echo strlen($rows["FECHA_MOV"]). "<br>"; 
echo $rows["FECHA_MOV"];
```

Me sale error:

Answer (score 0):

La función strtotime convierte desde fechas en inglés o en iso hacia timestamp php, $originalDate normalmente viene formateado según el idioma configurado en el SQLServer.